# Enviar e receber dados do MySQL com Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

E ae, tranquilidade?
Tenho uma activity que está listando uma série de produtos de um banco de dados MySQL. Preciso que, ao clicar em algum destes produtos, me transfira para outra activity, leve o ID do produto junto e, por esse ID recolhido, faça uma busca no MySQL e me retorne os detalhes daquele produto. 
Estou conseguindo passar o ID pra segunda activity, só não consigo pegar esse ID, jogar no php, fazer a busca no MySQL e retornar os resultados JSON pro android.

Na primeira activity eu estou conseguindo passar o ID:

```
    @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();

    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetalhesLivro.class);

    in.putExtra("pid", pid);

    startActivity(in);
 }
```

Na segunda, eu recupero:

```
EditText txtID;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhes_livro);


    Intent i = getIntent();

    pid = i.getStringExtra("pid");

    //Teste para ver se está pegando o ID
    //Jogando o ID num EditText
    txtID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputID);
    txtID.setText(pid);
}
```

Meu problema é daí em diante. Preciso jogar esse ID no php e me retornar os resultados.

Comment: Voce deve usar uma Asynctask para enviar este dado via POST para o servidor. Neste post o cara fez o que voce precisa fazer, pode ser útil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957989/inserting-data-into-mysql-using-http-post-and-asynctask-doesnt-work

Comment: vc tem a implementação no android para comunicar com o servidor PHP ?   vc tem a implementação que trata as requisições em PHP no servidor ?